# Postgres asynchronous procedure execution?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, functions

I have an ETL script entirely contained within a Postgres 9.3 procedure.  The script takes several hours to process, which is fine for our purposes.

What I haven't been able to find out is if there is a method within postgres to call a procedure, and then let it run on the server even if the client making the original call becomes disconnected.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you need, `screen` may be what you need.  It is used to run something on the remote system, without being disrupted by client disconnect.

Comment: Can you give me a documentation link for the screen keyword?  My googling skills aren't turning up anything that matches your description.

Comment: `man screen` if you are on a linux/unix machine

Comment: Ok I got it now, and as I worded the original question I think this would work.  Unfortunately we're using postgres on AWS RDS so a remote connection to the underlying OS isn't possible.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, PostgreSQL does not currently support having such an asynchronous call made to it, where the client is able to disconnect before the original call completes.  This has been discussed a number of times and there is ongoing work to implement a capability similar to this using a "pg_background" worker, but it's not in released versions of PG and it isn't clear when that will change.